# How to enable the super charger feature of MSI Z77 motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

I bought a MSI Z77 motherboard. They claim it has a "super charger" feature which allows you to charge your iPad via the USB. How do you enable this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's on page 37 of the manual for your motherboard (available here: http://us.msi.com/product/mb/Z77A-GD65.html#/?div=Manual).  It says:

> The JUSB1 connector [on your motherboard] supports MSI’s new SuperCharger
>   technology which provides quicker USB charging of your cellular phone
>   or other USB-powered devices. To enable this feature, please install
>   the MSI SuperCharger application on your computer. When the
>   SuperCharger application is turned on, the JUSB1 connector will
>   convert data channels to extra power channels to quickly charge your
>   connected device.
>
> Please note that when the SuperCharger application is turned on, data
>   transmission and synchronization over the JUSB1 connector will not
>   function. To enable the JUSB1 connector to function as a normal USB
>   2.0 connector, please turn off the SuperCharger application. When the computer is in stand-by or hibernation mode (S3/ S4/ S5) Super-
>   Charger mode will automatically be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it just means there are super-powered USB ports on the motherboard. If you look at the ports on the motherboard IO, you should have some USB ports that are orange coloured.

They provide extra power to charge larger devices.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer! I'll check it out right away.